# In android pdf viewer barteksc library, how to hide page number?

Tags: android

In my project, I am using `barteksc android pdf viewer` library. After hiding the pdf viewer, page number is still showing. How to hide page number in pdf viewer?

Comment: Read this and consider editing this question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

As I understand try this on

> PDFViewActivity.java

```
@Override
    public void onPageChanged(int page, int pageCount) {
        pageNumber = page;
        setTitle(String.format("%s %s / %s", pdfFileName,  pageCount));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
configurator = pdfView.fromFile(file);
configurator.defaultPage(0)
            .enableSwipe(false)
            .swipeHorizontal(false)
            .enableAnnotationRendering(false)
            .onLoad(this)
            .load();
```